# Room fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom not working properly

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I currently have this:

```
.addMigrations(
                        DatabaseMigration.FROM_14_TO_15,
                        DatabaseMigration.FROM_15_TO_16,
                        DatabaseMigration.FROM_16_TO_17,
                        DatabaseMigration.FROM_17_TO_18,
                        DatabaseMigration.FROM_18_TO_19,
                        DatabaseMigration.FROM_19_TO_20,
                        DatabaseMigration.FROM_20_TO_21,
                        DatabaseMigration.FROM_21_TO_22
                        )
```

I've incremented the database version to `23`, and initially created a migration `(22, 23)` but i just found out about `fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom` so I removed the migration(22,23) and replaced it with fallbak destructire migration

The problem is now if I set

`fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(22)`

I get the error:

`Inconsistency detected. A Migration was supplied to addMigration(Migration... migrations) that has a start or end version equal to a start version supplied to fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(int... startVersions). Start version: 22`

and if I set

`fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(23)`

I get

`A migration from 22 to 23 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) or allow for destructive migrations via one of the RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods.`

I am literally out of ideas and options. So, my wish was to clear the database and schema and everything when the app goes from version 22 to 23 and just load the new structure of the db... how can I solve this ?!

Answer (score 1):

> So, my wish was to clear the database and schema and everything when the app goes from version 22 to 23 and just load the new structure of the db... how can I solve this ?!

Just use `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration` and omit the migration for 22 to 23.  That is `fallbackToDestructiveMigration` only does the destruction if there is no migration available.

**Additional Re Comment**

> From all the docs I've read, it should be working with setting the ... from(22) ... and increasing the version of the db to 23 ... and then not provide a migration 22->23

Doing a quick test. Using version 1 through to 4, 4 being the destructive migration. Whilst migrations existed for 1-2 and 2-3 and also 1-3.

Then for version 4 all the existing migrations were omitted (i.e. `.addMigrations` commented out) and `.fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(1,2,3)` added.

The whole test suite being :-

**Test** (the @Entity annotated class) :-

```
@Entity
class Test {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long id = null;
    @NotNull
    String column1;
}
```

**TestDao** (the @Dao annotated abstract class) :-

```
@Dao
abstract class TestDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(Test test);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM test")
    abstract List<Test> getAllTestRows();
}
```

- only the getAllTestRows method being used, to force an open of the database.

**TestDatabase** (the @Database annotated class) :-

```
@Database(entities = {Test.class}, version = MainActivity.DATABASE_VERSION, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TestDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract TestDao getTestDao();

    private static final String TAG = "DBINFO";

    private static volatile TestDatabase INSTANCE = null;
    public static TestDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TestDatabase.class,MainActivity.DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    //.addMigrations(mig1_2,mig2_3,mig1_3)
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(1,2,3)
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static Migration mig1_2 = new Migration(1,2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Migration 1-2 invoked");
        }
    };
    private static Migration mig2_3 = new Migration(2,3) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Migration 2-3 invoked");
        }
    };
    private static Migration mig1_3 = new Migration(1,3) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Migration 1-3 invoked");
        }
    };
}
```

- noting that the `.addMigrations` is commented out (as per the final run)

and finally some activity code in **MainActivity** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
    public final static String DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db";

    TestDatabase db;
    TestDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = TestDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getTestDao();
        List<Test> testList = dao.getAllTestRows();
    }
}
```

**Testing**

**TEST1** brand new install at V4 (app uninstalled)

Runs fine, database via App Inspection (and result of `PRAGMA user_version` query):-

[image]

**Test2 part a** brand new install with

- `.fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(1,2,3)` commented out, and
  -`.addMigrations` re-instated (doesn't need to be).
- version set to 1

to prepare for part b, when run :-

[image]

**Test 2 part b** with above database (app not uninstalled)

- comment out .addMigrations
- introduce fallback....From
- set version to 4

runs ok with :-

[image]

**Test 3 part a**

- uninstall app
- out with .fallback....From
- in with .allowMigrations
- version set to 2

[image]

**Test 3 part b**

- out with .allowMigrations
- in with .fallback....From
- version 4

runs ok :-

[image]

(similar with version 3)

So what what .fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom is saying if the version is a listed version then it will destroy the database and there must be no migration that contradicts this.

- I haven't tested omitting e.g. 1,3.

So you want to have the .fallbackToDetsructiveMigrationFrom list being 1-22 inclusive and then the version set to 23 **without ANY migrations for 1 to 22**

Comment: I have this as well, `.fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,22)` should i just remove it entirely and replace it with fallbackDestructiveMigration() ? What happens to all the `.addMigration(..., ..., ..., )` ?Do I remove those completley as well ?

Comment: Also, what happens when in the future I will need a migration between 23->24 .... ? Do i put back the `.fallbackTo...From(1,2,3,....13, 22)` and `.addMigration(23_24)` ? What happens to the previous migrations though? Will they just fallback to destructive? i.e. if a user migrates from 10 directly to 24 ... will it destroy everything until 23, and then use the 23->24 migration ?

Comment: @AndreiBogdan I think this explains what ...from is for *If specific versions of your schema history cause errors that you cannot solve with migration paths, use fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom() instead. This method indicates that you want Room to fall back to destructive recreation only when migrating from specific versions.*  see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#handle-missing-migrations

Comment: I tried, I get the two above exceptions. From all the docs I've read, it should be working with setting the ... from(22) ... and increasing the version of the db to 23 ... and then not provide a migration 22->23 .... It SHOULD work .. but I have no idea why it doesn't. I'm definitely missing something, but I have no idea what !

Comment: @AndreiBogdan updated the answer with a basic test that hopefully explains how it works.

Comment: I thought it meant destroy database up to the specified version. Beyond that apply migrations? It's very confusing

Comment: @TheRealChx101 No it means fallback to a destructive migration (i.e. delete everything and build a new database (effectively)) in the absence of a migration being supplied. So no Migration then rather the fail saying there isn't a migration start as if there is no database. (hence why in java(generated) there is the **deleteAllTables** method (iirc)).